# ItemDecoration applies only after restart activity when using ListAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

When I was using RecyclerView, ItemDecoration worked perfectly. For now, after moving to ListAdapter my item decorations only appears after recreating activity. Actually, I understand why this is happening. When I was using RecyclerView, I used notifyDataSetChanged() to update my list. Now I am just using internal submitList, which uses methods to update only one item(not the whole dataset). But what am I supposed to do now? Downgrade to RecyclerView and its notifyDataSetChanged()? Is there another decision?

UPD.
My problem appears when I use StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, VERTICAL). When I just use LinearLayoutManager, the problem is gone, but I need both of them(layout managers).
My item decorations:

```
class SpacesItemDecoration(private var space: Int, private var type: String = "main_grid") : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        if (type == "main_grid") {
            //grid layout with 2 columns
            val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
            outRect.bottom = space

            if (layoutParams.spanIndex % 2 == 0) {
                outRect.right = space/2
            }
            else {
                outRect.left = space/2
            }
        }
        else if (type == "main_list") {
            //list layout
            outRect.bottom = space
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue somewhere else since you say recreating the Activity fixes it. I use item decorations with ListAdapter and it works fine.

Comment: What functionality you want to achieve? Show divider?

Comment: @Tenfour04 It works good only when I use LinearLayoutManager. But I need StaggerGridLayoutManager too. I updated the question.

Comment: @SamChen I show list of elements with StaggerGridLayoutManager(2 columns) and LinearLayoutManager. I have a problem with the first case, but not with the second one. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's a common problem of RecyclerView and ListAdapter. So, my problem is the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342034/recyclerview-itemdecoration-doesnt-update-after-item-is-removed-from-recyclervi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860875/recyclerview-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-refresh-bug).
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040395/12536790) helped me with the bug only when all elements of ListAdapter are visible. If there are more elements than fit on the screen, the bug appears again(it's a little bit different, but still with the decorations). So, the only way for me - downgrading to RecyclerView + using notifyDataSetChanged(). It's bad practice, but anyway.